# How I can read characters of a string?

Tags: c

I've a question, let's consider I've an array, char `A[50]`. Let's say, containing `"abcdef"`.

How I can read characters, let's say `"cd"` and save in another array, char `B[50]` ?

Comment: You can address individual characters, like A[2] and A[3], the more important question is probably "why cd"  and not "de" for example?

Comment: @Robert Ernest  If you mean C then use strncpy declared in the header <string.h>

Comment: Sorry, in C I would want but I was hoping maybe people who know C++ can know the answer

Comment: By "read characters, let's say "cd"" you mean, reading the characters on some specific location or search for some literals?

Comment: strncpy doesn't do what I want , it copies the first n characters in an other but what I want is coping , let's say, chars A[0] and A[1], then save in a char C then the chars A[2] and A[3] and save in char D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strncpy` to copy a substring from one array to another, and then terminate that substring:

```
int start = 2, count = 2
strncpy(B, A + start, count);
B[count] = '\0';
```

---

Answer to an older version of the question that was about C++:

However, there is a better approach: Don't use arrays, but `std::string` instead:

```
std::string A = "abcdef";
auto B = A.substr(2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use addresses and offsets you could just use `sprintf` such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char A[50] = "abcdef";
  char B[50] = {0};

  unsigned offset = 2;
  unsigned len    = 2;

  sprintf(B,"%.*s",len,&A[offset]);
  printf("%s",B);
  return(0);
}
```

This will result in filling B with the values of A[2] and A[3] and a string terminator = "cd\0".
If you don't want strings, but just the data in the elements of the array, then a simple [memcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) will do the trick.